# set bootstrap column's min-height automatically equal to size of another column

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

suppose I have this with `boostrap` loaded

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6"><img style="float:right" src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/w3schools.jpg"/></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6" style="background-color:#aaa">some text</div>
</div>
```

If you run snippet you will see that height of right-side column is equal to size of the content text in it.

**MY Question is:** Imagine source of image in left-side columns is random, (So it heigh will be random). How can I set min-height property of right-side column to size of left-side column which determines with size of `<img>` in it. in other hand I want some output like below image without manually setting `min-height` property:

[image: Figure of ideal output].

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This could work, although it depends upon setting the Bootstrap columns to `position: static`:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XRbGeq

Comment: Thanks for answer, But I need to do it in relative position.